# Should I set default react properties to null

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm tying to code as short as possible. We're writing react components with many props. The problem is my colleagues keep filling the code which seems very unnecessary to me. So is it correct to set null to all available values or only use propTypes to define property types? Because I don't see such usage examples and I think it is bad practice.

```
FormAutonumeric.defaultProps = {
    validationRules: null,
    onBlur: null,
    onFocus: null,
    inputClasses: null,
    showErrors: false,
    numericType: null,
    isFormValid: null,
    placeholder: null,
    onChange: null,
    disabled: null,
    children: null,
    vMin: null,
    vMax: null,
    prefix: null,
    suffix: null
};


FormAutonumeric.propTypes = {
    validationRules: PropTypes.shape({
        [PropTypes.string]: PropTypes.oneOfType([
            PropTypes.string,
            PropTypes.number,
            PropTypes.bool
        ])
    }),
    onBlur: PropTypes.func,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func,
    inputClasses: PropTypes.string,
    showErrors: PropTypes.bool,
    numericType: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]).isRequired,
    isFormValid: PropTypes.func,
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    onKeyUp: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    children: PropTypes.element,
    vMin: PropTypes.string,
    vMax: PropTypes.string,
    prefix: PropTypes.string,
    suffix: PropTypes.string
};
```

Comment: This might be a personal opinion kind of question rather than a call to best practices, but after several big React projects I prefer the short version of just declaring the PropTypes. I see no point in using defaults such as `null` bc `undefined` will render the same thing. I only declare defaultProps when really necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't set default properties to null if not necessary. I only do it if needed, i.e if you have a boolean property and you set it to false by default until somewhere in your code you set it to true. I'd say setting all your properties to null is not required by any means.

Comment: I see you have opened a bounty on your question. Did the answers below not answer your question? Anything in particular you were hoping for that was not in the answers?

Comment: @Chris I just want more attention. Otherwise your answer is ok.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Raul Rene's comment. Any unused props will be `undefined` which propbably won't make any difference in your code unless you are making strict checks, such as `myProp !== null` or something.

If you want to keep using `defaultProps` but still shorten your code a bit, you could always add the `isRequired` property to those props which are absolutely necessary for your component to work. For example, your component probably won't work as expected if the `onBlur` and `onFocus` props are not passed in, whereas it probably will work fine if `children` or `disabled` are not explicitly passed in.

Here's what this change would look like:

```
onBlur: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
onFocus: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
```

and remove these props from your `defaultProps` definition. A "fallback" prop doesn't make sense if a prop is "required" to be explicitly passed to the component.

I don't know how your code looks for your component, but the prop names suggest that your `defaultProps` definition can be reduced by at least half with this change.