# React defaultProps null vs undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Let's say we have component called Button and a property called classN which is not required.

```
Button.propTypes = {
  classN: PropTypes.string,
};
```

What are the differences between defining defaultProps for that property to null or to undefined?

```
Button.defaultProps = {
  classN: undefined,
}
```

**VS**

```
Button.defaultProps = {
  classN: null,
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it out?

Comment: There is no difference except one being null and the other being undefined.

Comment: It comes down to how you want to use that prop.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it out and did not see a difference but there may be potential different behaviours of the application with these two options.

Comment: That's useful information to add to your post. It shows that you have tried to find an answer yourself and clarifies what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: `null` is of type `object`, unlike `undefined` which is same as completely removing this line in `defaultProps`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting`null` values to props can be intentional and be used to dictate lifecycle logic. Adding to @hemant-kumar's comment, default props are by default `undefined` and can be used to indicate values that have not been set but will be.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809178/react-js-default-prop-is-not-used-with-null-is-passed#34809686)

Answer (score 1):

@fjplaurr I need to put an answer since I am not eligible to put a comment.
 By default, properties will be undefined. So it all depends, how you consume properties in your code.
In case you check if a property is undefined then you will be putting a different check and in case of the null check will say if property!=null.
I believe 
[Should I set default react properties to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755925/should-i-set-default-react-properties-to-null) might help to choose the best between the two.